# Change basePath for swagger-ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I used swagger project create to stand up an API for a node service. I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node). I'm also using swagger-tools to serve the swagger-ui.

I'd like to dynamically change the basePath of the API and its documentation from '/' and '/docs' to routingPath and routingPath + '/docs'.

I am able to change the basePath of my swagger API spec, but I'm not sure how to change the basePath of the swagger-ui. My code looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const defaultRoutingPath = '/api/collection';
const defaultPort = 3000;

var path = require('path');
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var SwaggerUi = require('swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-ui');
var app = require('express')();
module.exports = app; // for testing

var routingPath = process.env.ROUTING_PATH || defaultRoutingPath;

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname // required config
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.basePath = routingPath; // this works

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(path.join(routingPath, 'docs'));
  })

  // enable SwaggerUI
  app.use(swaggerExpress.runner.swaggerTools.swaggerUi({
    basePath: routingPath  // this has no effect
  }));

  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);

  var port = process.env.PORT || defaultPort;
  app.listen(port);

  if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/hello']) {
    console.log('try this:\ncurl http://127.0.0.1:' + port + path.join(routingPath, '/hello?name=Scott'));
  }
});
```

If I run this service, I will find my API spec at
http://localhost:3000/api/collection

And my docs page at
http://localhost:3000/docs

I would like to serve the docs page at
http://localhost:3000/api/collection/docs

I attempted to do that by passing a basePath option to the swaggerUi constructor.

```
  // enable SwaggerUI
  app.use(swaggerExpress.runner.swaggerTools.swaggerUi({
    basePath: routingPath  // this has no effect
  }));
```

That didn't work. Anyone know how to configure the basePath of the swagger-ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question following essentially [this guidance](https://github.com/shawngong/Swagger-Node-Express-For-Existing-APIs).

The key was to add a second express app (subpath) and use a routingPath from the main app. Here's the code.

```js
'use strict';
    
const defaultRoutingPath = '/api/collection';
const defaultPort = 80;

var path = require('path');
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var SwaggerUi = require('swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-ui');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var subpath = express();
module.exports = app; // for testing

var routingPath = process.env.ROUTING_PATH || defaultRoutingPath;

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname, // required config
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  
  app.use(routingPath, subpath);
  
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(path.join(routingPath, 'docs'));
  })
  
  swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.basePath = routingPath;

  // enable SwaggerUI
  subpath.use(swaggerExpress.runner.swaggerTools.swaggerUi());

  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);

  var port = process.env.PORT || defaultPort;
  app.listen(port);

  if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/health']) {
    console.log('try this:\ncurl http://127.0.0.1:' + port + path.join(routingPath, '/health'));
  }
});
```

Now my docs are available here:
http://localhost:3000/api/collection/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Using spring-boot I could remap

```
public class CustomResourceMapping extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  { 
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController(
        "/configuration/ui", 
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController(
        "/configuration/security", 
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
    }
}
```

but still have a problem, part of the doc is generated, 
then a javascript bug is occuring:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2 
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/configuration/ui".                 jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2 
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/swagger-resources".                jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2 
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs".                      swagger-ui.min.js:10
swagger-ui.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined    swagger-ui.min.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (swagger-ui.min.js:1)
    at Object.10 (swagger-ui.min.js:2)
    at Object.f [as inverse] (handlebars-2.0.0.js:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (handlebars-2.0.0.js:27)
    at Object.9 (swagger-ui.min.js:2)
    at Object.f [as inverse] (handlebars-2.0.0.js:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (handlebars-2.0.0.js:27)
    at Object.main (swagger-ui.min.js:2)
    at e (handlebars-2.0.0.js:27)
    at s.render (swagger-ui.min.js:10)
```